# Building Shindig locally

Tags: maven, opensocial, apache-shindig

I want to use Shindig as an OpenSocial container. In order to do that I want to add more features to Shindig's current ones, thus I have to build its source code locally.

I have downloaded the source code from Shindig's SVN at: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/shindig/trunk/
I'm trying to build it using Maven (3.0.3) but with no success. I get the following compilation errors:

```
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (def
> ault-testCompile) on project shindig-gadgets: Compilation failure:
> Compilation failure: [ERROR]
> \Users\I064832\Desktop\shindig\java\gadgets\src\test\java\org\apache\shindig\gadgets\http\Fa
> keHttpServer.java:[27,16] cannot access org.mortbay.util.Attributes
> [ERROR] class file for org.mortbay.util.Attributes not found [ERROR]
> public abstract class FakeHttpServer extends Server { [ERROR]
> \Users\I064832\Desktop\shindig\java\gadgets\src\test\java\org\apache\shindig\gadgets\http\Fa
> keHttpServer.java:[32,13] cannot access
> org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle [ERROR] class file for
> org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle not found [ERROR] server = new
> Server(port); [ERROR]
> \Users\I064832\Desktop\shindig\java\gadgets\src\test\java\org\apache\shindig\gadgets\http\Fa
> keHttpServer.java:[33,14] cannot access
> org.mortbay.component.LifeCycle [ERROR] class file for
> org.mortbay.component.LifeCycle not found [ERROR] context = new
> Context(server, "/", Context.SESSIONS); [ERROR]
> \Users\I064832\Desktop\shindig\java\gadgets\src\test\java\org\apache\shindig\gadgets\http\Fa
> keHttpServer.java:[35,10] doStart() has protected access in
> org.mortbay.jetty.Server [ERROR]
> \Users\I064832\Desktop\shindig\java\gadgets\src\test\java\org\apache\shindig\gadgets\http\Fa
> keHttpServer.java:[42,10] doStop() has protected access in
> org.mortbay.jetty.Server [ERROR]
> \Users\I064832\Desktop\shindig\java\gadgets\src\test\java\org\apache\shindig\gadgets\http\Ba
> sicHttpFetcherTest.java:[53,15] operator != cannot be applied to
> org.apache.shindig.gadgets.http.Ech oServer,<nulltype> . . .
```

I see that Shindig 2.0 was released a year ago, maybe there is a mismatch between Shindig's code to its dependencies?
How can I eliminate these errors?
Thanks,
Tomer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a mismatch between some version of Jetty and the code in Shindig.

You may have local maven artifacts or a custom maven configuration.  If that's the case you can remove them and try again.  On unix-like systems this involves removing the contents of the `~/.m2/repository`.